# Ensuring same labels used by cv::connectedComponentsWithStats as used by cv::cuda::labelComponents

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a feature mask calculated from a neural network in a CUDA buffer. In order to clean up the feature mask, I plan to use connected components labeling to extract only the largest connected component. This mask is then going to be used for further GPU calculations, so in order to minimize data transfers, I want to copy from the device to CPU, perform `cv::connectedComponentsWithStats` on the CPU mask while simultaneously computing `cv::cuda::labelComponents` on the CUDA mask and then instead of copying the CPU mask back to the GPU, only send the index of the component and update the existing CUDA mask according to that label.

Since the algorithms might be different for with stats and without, I want to ensure that the labels correspond (label `i` from `cv::connectedComponentsWithStats` will match label `i` from `cv::cuda::labelComponents`. Is this guaranteed, and if not, what can be done to find the map between the labels?

Comment: Have you tried returning the coordinates of the centroid? Even if the centroid calculations are off between the two implementations, if you have a labeled image on the CPU side, you'll be able to retrieve the label for that pixel.

Comment: @beaker In general, that would work, but the centeroid of a connected component isn't guaranteed to be on the component. A ring, for example.

Comment: Ah, good point. But any arbitrary pixel that *is* guaranteed to be in the component will work.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be too expensive to do a quick search for a sample pixel inside the bounding box that the connected components stats give me though, so that probably works. Thank you for the idea!